# Transferring a texture 1 to 1

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, baking, vertex-colors

What i have is:

- an exported .ply and .obj from MagicaVoxel

  .obj has it's texture stored in this way [image]

  .ply is just a 1:1 mesh with all its textures stored in vertices
- a cleaned up duplicate

What i want is to transfer the texture 1 to 1 from either mesh(.obj or .ply), but the problem i run into is that there is a pretty big margin of error when trying to bake in Blender [image]

The mesh on the left is the cleaned up mesh with a 128x128 texture applied to it

The mesh on the right is the original in the form of .obj

When baked to a higher-res destination texture, the margin is smaller, but still noticeably there.

Baking from vertex colors using this setup yields a similar result with a similar kind of mismatch.
[image]

These are my baking settings.

[image]

I've tried changing pretty much everything, including baking with a cage, but still can't reach a 1 to 1 transfer. I can't imagine this being impossible to do so it must be something to do with how i approach it.

Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT: Made some progress by using the "Snap to pixels" function when unwrapping the gun. It's fidgety and i ended up having to unwrap it a couple of times and manually moving it a bit to get the vertices snap to "correct" pixels. Basically fidget with it until you get lucky.
[image]

There's still a lot of warping going on, which is i think to do with the fact that it's a 128x128 texture and it's nowhere near being 1 to 1, but it's better.

I think.

EDIT 2: Cleaning up the UV helped a bit. I overlapped some islands and packed it a bit neater, which made for more space for individual islands and better alignment overall. Still not perfect, but with manual adjustment in blender and photoshop, you can get decent results relatively quickly.

Comment: 2 days ago I thought I messed up one of my model's UV's because I saw a seem in Material Preview mode that I never noticed before. However, when I entered Render View, that seam was gone again. Material View is very imprecise. Your Blender image shows Material View. Please confirm the problem still exists when you render.

Comment: @hatinacat2000 Yeah, i'm aware of that issue and, unfortunately, it's not it.